# How to I use optional vars with mutable collections?

Tags: swift

I can't seem to get collections to be mutable when they are assigned to optional variables. In the sample code below, the NonOptional works as expected. A var will keep the mutable state on the collection. No local vars, I can use the variable field directly. However I am not sure how to have vars with immutable collections, should I assume "let" instead of "var" would do the trick?

Nevertheless, looking at the Optional class, one requires a local var to give the collection a mutable state (even if XCode suggests append() when I don't use the local var). Is this really the way I am supposed to write code to update collection by adding local variables? Is there a more concise way without using a local var? I am curious to know if the assignment of a collection is a simple alias or does it do a copy, either shallow or deep underneath?

```
   class NonOptional {
        var exclamation: String[] // using var should set that collection as mutable...

        init() {
            self.exclamation = []
        }

        func write() {
            self.exclamation.append("exclamation")
        }

        func delete() {
            if self.exclamation.count > 0 {
                self.exclamation.removeAtIndex(0)
            }
        }
    }

    class Optional {
        var question: String[]? // using var should set that collection as mutable...

        init() {
            self.question = []
        }

        func write() {
            var local = self.question! // copy or pass by ref?
            local.append("question")    // why can't I just do self.foo!.append("foo") ?
        }

        func delete() {
            if self.question!.count > 0 {
                var local = self.question!
                local.removeAtIndex(0)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: unless you call a `mutating` method on the `local` or on the `question`, they will point to the _same_ instance. after you call any `mutating` method on any they will point to different instances. creating the new instance will take `O(n)` time. you can read more about it here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/ClassesAndStructures.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was asked when Swift 1 was still in beta, and much has changed since (though I'm not entirely sure if this particular feature didn't exist in Swift 1).

For posterity, mutating an optional array is no problem in Swift 3. Here's how you would do it:

```
var strings: [String]? = ["a", "b"]
strings?[0] = "A"
// strings is now Optional(["A", "b"])
strings?.append("c")
// strings is now Optional(["A", "b", "c"])
strings?.remove(at: 1)
// strings is now Optional(["A", "c"])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var question: String[]? // using var should set that collection as mutable...
```

This is wrong. The `var` there says that the optional reference is 'mutable', that is it can be `nil` or set to an actual array. Swift then defaults to making the array non mutable.

Many of these smaller details concerning arrays and mutability are a bit in flux at the moment, I expect there to be fixes, changes and a clear definition of what is supposed to happen in the coming weeks.

Comment: Good to hear. I know that it's not a good place to give opinions, so let me make a suggestion instead, even if I get slammed for it: I've seen myself fighting issues like this one a lot with Swift. Maybe the language tries too hard to be back-compatible, not sure. In order to save a keyword like mut/mutating, this syntax is not easy to write or even to read. I would prefer something like in Rust or OCaml when you can explicitly tell vars are mutative or not. Today non-mutable arrays are in fact mutable minus size change, so I think a new keyword could fix things both in clarity and correctness

Comment: The issue where you can mutate immutable arrays as long as you don't change their size is apparently going to get fixed in a future version at least. Se we will get true immutable arrays.

Comment: In the meantime, what do you recommend I do? Stick to NSMutable arrays with a bridge like syntax or use the var trick above, essentially redefining the array as mutable for the scope of the function? Just trying to figure out what is the best way to deal with what seems to be a big deficiency in the language design. I am a bit muffled to see that this is going to be fixed only later. After all, memory management feels like it should be more strongly anchored into the language blueprints

Comment: I don't know you specific situation, but I would use a default empty array, so that I don't have an optional type. Then I just have a nice mutable array that defaults the the empty array. Otherwise, I would use your trick from above. Btw, you can directly initialize the property in place `var myArray = String[]()`